# Estoy realizando un reporte en PDF pero solo me imprime el ultimo registro (php,mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

espero estén muy bien el día de hoy.

Tengo el siguiente código que seria mi reporte en PDF, estoy usando la librería tcpdf.

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';


    $pdf_orientation = 'P';
    $pdf_unit = 'px';
    $pdf_pageformat = 'A4';
    $pdf_unicode = true;
    $pdf_encoding = 'UTF-8';

    $pdf = new TCPDF($pdf_orientation, $pdf_unit, $pdf_pageformat, $pdf_unicode, $pdf_encoding, false);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false); //para eliminar la linea superio del pdf por defecto
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false); //eliminar linea del footer

    //set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(20, 20, 20);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(20);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(20);

    //set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 20);
 
    //set image scale factor
    //$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    //set some language-dependent strings
    //$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 10);
    $pdf->AddPage();


$html ='
<style>
    .imgs{
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        border:1px solid red;
        margin:90px;
        padding:50px;
    }
</style>';

include('config.php');
$queryCampostabla    = ("SELECT * FROM recibir_items");
$resulCampostabla    = mysqli_query($con, $queryCampostabla);
$cantidadItems       = mysqli_num_rows($resulCampostabla);

$dir = 'imagenesQR/';



while ($row_expo = mysqli_fetch_array($resulCampostabla)) {
    $codigoId     = $row_expo['id_reci'];
    $codigo       = $row_expo['codigo_reci'];
    $descrip_reci = $row_expo['descrip_reci'];
    $ubi          = $row_expo['ubi'];

    $name        = $codigoId.".png";
    if(!file_exists($dir))
      mkdir($dir);
    $filename = $dir.$name;
  
    $tamanio   = 10;  //Tamaño de Pixel
    $level     = 'H'; //Precisión Baja
    $frameSize = 1;  //Tamaño en blanco

QRcode::png($codigoId, $filename, $level, $tamanio, $frameSize); 

$html = '';
$a = 0;
$nRegistros = $cantidadItems;
$html .= '<table style="text-align: center;" align="center">';
for ($i = 0; $i < $nRegistros; $i++) {
    if ($a == 0) {
        $html .= '<tr>';
    }
    $html .= '<td style="padding: 20px;"> <span style="font-size: 8px !important;">"'.$descrip_reci.'"</span>
    <br> <span style="text-align: center !important;">"'.$codigo.'"</span>
    <br> <span>"'.$ubi.'"</span>
    <br> <img src="'.$filename.'" class="romi"/></td>';
    if ($a == 2) {
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $a = 0;
    } else if ($i == ($nRegistros - 1)) {
        $html .= '</tr>';
    } else {
        $a++;
    }
}
$html .= '</table>';
}


$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output('demo.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

El reporte se genera sin problemas y de la forma en que lo necesito, el único inconveniente es que tengo en total 4 registros en mi tabla, pero solo me imprime el ultimo registro 4 veces.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: a las variables que les pasas al pdf le cargas un valor atras de otro.. el que queda es el ultimo.. la variable no puede tener mas de un valor.. si no, deberias usar un array

Comment: Hola @gbianchi de que forma podría implementar el uso del array en mi código? me podrías dar un ejemplo por favor.

Comment: no se php.. alguien podra darte una respuesta mejor, pero espero hayas entendido tu problema..

Comment: En cada iteración del ciclo estás sobrescribiendo el contenido `$html = '';`. Declara esa variable antes del ciclo y ya debería funcionar.

Comment: Hola @Triby seria antes del while o antes del for?

Comment: Mueve esa línea antes del `while` y eso es todo.

Comment: Es que alli esta el gran detalle, cual linea? si muchas tiene esa etiqueta $html = ''; :)

Comment: @Triby ya movi esta linea $html = ''; antes del while, ahora si imprime todos los productos, pero igual me los repite muchas veces todos.

Comment: Sí, ya vi; lo que pasa es que estás haciendo dos ciclos, con el `while` es suficiente, necesitas quitar el `for`, por supuesto, dejando solo lo que está dentro.

Comment: @Triby ok, el problema es que ya quite el for, pero ahora todos los productos los deja uno debajo del otro, como puedo hacer para que estén uno al lado del otro y no debajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que dentro del ciclo estás reinicializando la variable `$html` y te deja solo el último registro, perdiendo incluso los estilos. Además, el ciclo `for` no es necesario, porque multiplicas un solo registro por la cantidad de resultados obtenidos de la consulta.

Para tener 2 celdas, es necesario declarar la variable `$a`, que usas como contador, también fuera del ciclo y, dentro, analizar si el contador es número par, es decir, cuando `($a % 2)` devuelve cero:

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';


    $pdf_orientation = 'P';
    $pdf_unit = 'px';
    $pdf_pageformat = 'A4';
    $pdf_unicode = true;
    $pdf_encoding = 'UTF-8';

    $pdf = new TCPDF($pdf_orientation, $pdf_unit, $pdf_pageformat, $pdf_unicode, $pdf_encoding, false);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false); //para eliminar la linea superio del pdf por defecto
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false); //eliminar linea del footer

    //set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(20, 20, 20);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(20);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(20);

    //set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 20);
 
    //set image scale factor
    //$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    //set some language-dependent strings
    //$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 10);
    $pdf->AddPage();


$html ='
<style>
    .imgs{
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        border:1px solid red;
        margin:90px;
        padding:50px;
    }
</style>';

include('config.php');
$queryCampostabla    = ("SELECT * FROM recibir_items");
$resulCampostabla    = mysqli_query($con, $queryCampostabla);
$cantidadItems       = mysqli_num_rows($resulCampostabla);

$dir = 'imagenesQR/';

// Crear tabla y fila antes del ciclo
$html .= '<table style="text-align: center;" align="center"><tr>';
// Definir contador de filas fuera del ciclo
$a = 0;
while ($row_expo = mysqli_fetch_array($resulCampostabla)) {
    $codigoId     = $row_expo['id_reci'];
    $codigo       = $row_expo['codigo_reci'];
    $descrip_reci = $row_expo['descrip_reci'];
    $ubi          = $row_expo['ubi'];

    $name        = $codigoId.".png";
    if(!file_exists($dir))
      mkdir($dir);
    $filename = $dir.$name;
  
    $tamanio   = 10;  //Tamaño de Pixel
    $level     = 'H'; //Precisión Baja
    $frameSize = 1;  //Tamaño en blanco

QRcode::png($codigoId, $filename, $level, $tamanio, $frameSize); 
    // Si el contador es par, cerrar fila y crear nueva
    if ($a > 0 && $a % 2 == 0) {
        $html .= '</tr><tr>';
        $a = 0;
    }
    $html .= '<td style="padding: 20px;"> <span style="font-size: 8px !important;">"'.$descrip_reci.'"</span>
    <br> <span style="text-align: center !important;">"'.$codigo.'"</span>
    <br> <span>"'.$ubi.'"</span>
    <br> <img src="'.$filename.'" class="romi"/></td>';
    // Incrementar contador
    $a++;
}
// Cerrar fila y tabla al salir del ciclo
$html .= '</tr></table>';


$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output('demo.pdf', 'I');
// Fin de archivo, no incluyas etiqueta de cierre
```

**Nota importante:** No uses la etiqueta de cierre de PHP `?>` al final de tus *scripts*, porque podrías enviar espacios o saltos de línea que van a "romper" el contenido del PDF. De igual forma, la etiqueta de apertura `<?php` debe estar en la primera línea y primera columna para evitar el mismo problema.

Comment: hola @Triby excelente tu respuesta, ahora si funciona perfecto. muchas gracias por tu ayuda.